# Update pandas column based on comparison of two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to assign df2's "ID" for rows in df1 that have the same latitude and longitude as a row in df2, or close enough according to `max_lat_offset` and `max_lon_offset`.

This for loop version does what I want, but is slow with large datasets:

```
for df1_index, df1_row in df1.iterrows():
    for df2_index, df2_row in df_2.iterrows():
        if abs(df2_row['latitude'] - df1_row['lat']) < max_lat_offset and abs(df2_row['longitude'] - df1_row['lon']) < max_lon_offset:
            df1.at[df1_index,'id'] = df2_row['ID']
```

Is it possible to use a clever pandas/numpy trick to work this out? I have tried using `np.where`

```
df1['id'] = np.where(abs(df2.latitude - df1.lat) < max_lat_offset and abs(df2.longitude - df1.lon) < max_lon_offset, df2['ID'], None)
```

But I get `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous`.

Pandas experts, what's the optimal way to do this?

**Update - here is what the data in the df's look like:**

df1:

```
lat lon id
0   53.045913   -1.410764   NaN
1   57.148783   -6.211683   NaN
2   51.421184   0.824588    NaN
3   51.504658   -0.104954   NaN
4   51.464968   -0.073252   NaN
```

df2:

```
latitude    longitude   ID
0   51.387471   -3.406610   1
1   55.735807   -4.888574   2
2   53.716417   -1.281885   3
3   52.448628   0.725273    4
4   52.230195   -0.881341   5
```

The expected output is df1, modified so that `id` has the df2 `ID` value of a row with sufficiently close latitude and longitude.

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected output?

Comment: @jezrael hopefully that clarifies?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
df1['id'] = np.where((abs(df2.latitude - df1.lat) < max_lat_offset) &
       (abs(df2.longitude - df1.lon) < max_lon_offset), df2['ID'], None)
```

Comment: As far as I know it will subtract values at same index in both data frames, provided the number of rows in both are same.

Comment: I'm afraid @jezrael is correct, that would only perform the check for close lat/lon at rows of the same index between the dataframes. I need to check all rows as I have done in the for loop version

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is use cross join with all combinations of value in new `DataFrame`, then you can filtering by condition - but if large DataFrames need huge RAM:

```
df = df1.assign(a=1).merge(df2.assign(a=1), on='a')

df = df[((df.latitude - df.lat).abs() < max_lat_offset) & 
        ((df.longitude - df.lon).abs() < max_lon_offset)]
```